# How do I get all the elements of data.d

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I have a server method that returns a collection of instances of my custom class. I know that to access those objects in AJAX success callback function I can  say `data.d`. And to access the first object I'd write `data.d[0]`. But how do I get all the elements of data.d? I won't to iterate through all the objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you know `data.d` is an array.. In your success callback simply iterate through the items in the array:

```
    success: function (data) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {
            console.log(data.d[i]);
        }
    }
```

If you're using jQuery you can also use [$.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/).  It takes a callback with two parameters - the index into the collection and the value at that index:

```
    success: function (data) {
        $.each(data.d, function (i, v) {
            console.log(i, v);
        });
    }
```

Comment: That's actually correct. Is there anyway to do it with $.each?